# What is "the day of the L-RD" found in Isaiah 13:6 and elsewhere and when does/did it occur?

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

What is "the day of the L-RD" found in Isaiah 13:6 and elsewhere and when does/did it occur?:

> JPS Tanakh 1917 Isaiah 13:6 Howl ye; for **the day of the L-RD** is at
>   hand; As destruction from the Almighty shall it come.

It seems to be described as a day of judgment. Is it a day of judgment primarily on the nations or on Israel?

Also, is it associated with the arrival of the messiah?

Comment: Read in the subsequent verses. It should become very obvious, especially with verse 9, that this refers to the Day of Judgement in the end times.

Comment: @DonielF Smells strongly like an answer...

Comment: @DonielF Nothing in scripture is "very obvious" to me! Hasn't  Babylon been destroyed already?

Comment: @Ruminator How do you mean? When was Babylon previously destroyed?

Comment: It is in ruins today:  https://www.ancient.eu/babylon/

Comment: @Ruminator Without becoming too "kabbalistic", Babylon is still very much alive spiritually... Similar to the presence of Amalek today. :)

Comment: @ezra I'm inclined now to accept the explanation that I read in my research yesterday that the term "day of the L-ORD" is referring to "when G-d visits" in regard to a particular situation and that the term does not refer to the one ultimate event.

Comment: @Ruminator Did you find this explanation among Jewish sources? If so, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: @ezra It was from a Christian commentator.